# BootStrap Submit Button Not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a simple front end for displaying images using BootStrap. However before using BootStrap the button to view images was working fine but after styling the page using bootstrap, It does nothing, Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?  When I tried seeing in Developer tools of Chrome , I get 2 exceptions:

```
Uncaught Error: You must include the utils.js file before tether.js
    at tether.js:4
(anonymous) @ tether.js:4
bootstrap.min.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: Tether is not defined
```

Code:

```
    <html lang="en">


    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title></title>
        <script src="script/tether.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script/tether.js"></script>
        <script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"></link>

        <script src="script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="mt-4" align='center'> Demo Website </h1><br>

        <div class="container" style="width:300px; background-color:ghostwhite;">

                <div class="form-group">


                <form  action='viewimages2.php' method="GET">
                    <button class="btn-block btn btn-info" align='center' type="submit" name="Submit"> View Images </button>
                </form>

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Working Code without Bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1 align='center'>Demo Website/h1><br>
        <button align='center' type="button" onclick="window.location='Register.php';" value="Register"> Register </Button> 
         <button align='center' type="button" onclick="window.location='Login.php';" value="Login"> Login </Button> 
        <form action='viewimages2.php' method="GET">
           <button type='submit' name="Submit"> View Images </button>
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is unclear about "You must include the utils.js file before tether.js"?

Comment: Because including utils.js before tether.js gave the same exception, but it is cleared now after trying out solution by Swellar but button is still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, put the `jquery.min.js` before the other `.js` files. I think you can remove `tether.js` since you are already using `tether.min.js`

```
<script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error message complains that `utils.js` is missing. Why are you moving `jquery.min.js`?!

Comment: There is no exception now but button is still not working

Comment: @Quentin I thought that `utils.js` is part of `jquery.min.js`, and most of the time, moving `jquery.min.js` to the topmost can solve many problems relating to functions not working